# Sort and store a list of two values

Tags: c#, linq

I have to store about 100k items. Each of them contains *two values* (fields?)

```
  DateTime, Decimal
```

I have to *sort* these items by `DateTime` values as well. However, my try 
*failed* with *compile-time error*:

```
  List<DateTime, Decimal> list = ... // <- Compile time error
  ...
  list.Sort();
```

How can I solve the problem of *storing* and *sorting* such items? Is it possible using Linq?

Comment: List in C# only has one generic type parameter, e.g. `List<DateTime>`. Can you show your real code?

Comment: `List<DateTime, decimal>` won't compile. Use a `Dictionary` or a List of `Tuple` / `KeyValuePair` or a custom object

Comment: Where do you get that list *from*? If it's a database, use the db-functionality to sort it (helped by an index)

Comment: It sounds more like you need your own class that stores a `DateTime` and a `Decimal`, What have you tried? Why does it need to use linq?

Comment: Assuming DateTime is unique, you can use a [`SortedList<DateTime, decimal>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will do the sorting for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can't declare `List<T>` like that

```
  List<DateTime, decimal> list // compile time error
```

since `List<T>` can have *only one* generic parameter (that's `T`).
The most, probably, popular solution to that is using

```
  Tuple<T1, T2, ...>
```

in your case

```
  Tuple<DateTime, decimal>
```

So the implementation could be

```
  List<Tuple<DateTime, decimal>> list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, decimal>>() {
    new Tuple<DateTime, decimal> (DateTime.Now, 2),
    new Tuple<DateTime, decimal> (DateTime.Now, 1),
    new Tuple<DateTime, decimal> (DateTime.Now, 3),
  };

  // Just sorting the existing list
  list.Sort((Comparison<Tuple<DateTime, decimal>>) 
    ((left, right) => left.Item1.CompareTo(right.Item1)));

  // To create another (sorted) list by Linq:
  List<Tuple<DateTime, decimal>> result = list
    .OrderBy(item => item.Item1);
```